# Terminator 2 1990 Harley Davidson Fatboy FLSTF technical information

Tags: motorcycle, suspension, harley-davidson

I am doing a project for class about the Harley Davidson Fatboy, and I need to find the values for the spring constant of the bike used in Terminator 2, and whether or not it used a custom suspension. I found the normal suspension used in the 1990 Fatboy are telescopic forks with a 5.1 inch wheel travel in the front and twin shocks with a 4.1 inch wheel travel in the rear, but I cannot find their actual values.

Comment: Sounds more like a question for Movies.SE

Comment: That or [Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com/) since he wants the spring constant.

Comment: Harley does not publish it's spring constants.  As well, many manufacturers us progressive rate springs that are not a constant.  If you were to use a motorcycle with an Ohlin's suspension you can get all of this information from them.  An example would be a Ducati Panigal S or an Aprilia RSV4 Factory.  Good luck, hope you get an A.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is regarding a special motorcycle for a movie and there is now way for anyone can know the answer to the question.